# OpenMP Segmentation Fault When Parallelizing Simple Loop

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, openmp

I have a function that takes in an array and updates an array in a for loop like such:

```
void compute(double values[], int num_points, double ders[]){
    for(int i = 0; i < num_points; ++i)
    {
        double a = values[i* 3 + 0 ];
        double b = values[i* 2 + 1 ];
        ders[i*4 + 0] = a * b;
        ders[i*4 + 1] = a * a;
        ders[i*4 + 2] = b * b;
        ders[i*4 + 3] = b * a * a;
   }
}
```

All of this is well and good but then I update the code to try to do things in parallel with OpenMP like

```
void compute(double values[], int num_points, double ders[]){
   omp_set_dynamic(0);
   omp_set_num_threads(2);
   #pragma omp parallel for
    for(int i = 0; i < num_points; ++i)
    {
        double a = values[i* 3 + 0 ];
        double b = values[i* 2 + 1 ];
        ders[i*4 + 0] = a * b;
        ders[i*4 + 1] = a * a;
        ders[i*4 + 2] = b * b;
        ders[i*4 + 3] = b * a * a;
   }
}
```

And now I'm getting Segmentation Faults.

I feel like I must be overwriting some value in two threads -- but everything in ders and values is indexed according to 'i' so it feels like it should be trivial to parallelize.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Run your program in single-threaded mode through valgrind, or compile with `-fsanitize=address` and look for errors.

Comment: This line looks fishy: `double a = values[i* 3 + 0 ];`, I guess that should read `i * 2` instead? That would explain the segmentation fault, also keep in mind this would also happen in the sequential version, but probably only for a larger input, as it was however you were probably just getting wrong results. This is all assuming the factor is in fact wrong of course.

Comment: Debuggers are your friends in finding out where exactly the segmentation fault happens.